# Java - Malformed URL - Not correct - No protocol

Tags: java, file, url, exception, malformed

This code:

```
        String file = "";
    String filename = "";
    try{
        BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("filename.txt")));//get file name
        while (ins.ready()) {
           filename = ins.readLine();
        }
        ins.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }

        String[] sa = filename.split("/");
        file = sa[sa.length - 1];

        try {
            System.out.println(filename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Prints:

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
```

When I try to do :

```
         URL url = new URL(filename);
```

I get the malformed URL exception : no protocol
This is happening for no reason. If I manually assign the filename string to 
"http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt" it will work perfectly , is there something wrong with the file reader?

The thing goes like

Read a string from the file and then make it a URL! Stop editing wrongly!

Comment: `readme.txt` is not a valid URL.

Comment: filename = the long thing , and why isnt it a valid url , @Sotiris Delimanolis , you misunderstood the whole thing. The whole issue is happening when I am trying to make filename a url.

Comment: My apologies to you and bobble. I have retracted my answer. I will try to make up for it by making sure you get this answered.

Comment: @MickJ OK , but there had happened a wrong edit that got approoved somehow...

Comment: @user3310358: Are you absolutely sure that there's no whitespace at the front or end of the string `filename` when you pass it to `new URL(filename)`? E.g., `System.out.println("'" + filename + "'");`

Comment: At the point in code where you call `new URL(filename)` evidently `filename` no longer is correct. Dump the filename there. And maybe reconsider the code. Maybe with other means like: `String filename = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("filename.txt")).get(0);`

Comment: @JoopEggen Why is filename no longer correct? And DarkDust yes , there is no such space or so... The file filename.txt does not have any other lines or spaces or...

Comment: Are you calling a function and expecting filename to be populated?  I don't think there is enough information here to help you solve this problem, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Just added working code. Can you please add printstacktrace in you file reading catch block before your next run. I have tested it and can vouch for its validity. Sorry about my first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea:

It could be that the file is saved in UTF-8, but with an extra BOM character at the file beginning. This is a zero-width Unicode space.

```
filename = filename.replaceFirst("^\uFFFE", "");
```

Comment: +1 That always happens to me whenever I'm working with files with BOM's. I wish libraries would take care of them for me but that may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score -2):

Working code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class MyFileReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String file = "";
        String filename = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader ins = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("c:\\filename.txt")));// get file name
            while (ins.ready()) {
                filename = ins.readLine();
            }
            ins.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] sa = filename.split("/");
        file = sa[sa.length - 1];

        try {
            System.out.println(filename);
            URL url = new URL(filename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Contents of filename.txt:

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
```

Output from program:

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt
readme.txt
```

Errors/Exceptions:
**None**

Comment: Since the first Sysout is printing the valid URL, `filename` is already set correctly!

Comment: You dont get it , this is not what I want to do . I get a string from a file named filename.txt . After that I transform the String to a url

Comment: Now that the answer in the code is fully functional to the OPs spec, without the unstated information about UTF-8, how about taking back the negative votes?

Comment: What about removing the answer? :)  I mean, this is not a solution to the issue, is it?

Comment: Based on the information provided in the question, this is a working solution to the problem that lists the code, the inputs, the outputs, and hence does not deserve negative votes anymore. Of course I could not get into OPs head or make guesses.